# jQuery Ajax PHP Email form only returning first checkbox value

Tags: php, jquery, email, checkbox

I am trying to use jQuery for the first time and have a problem returning multiple checkbox values. I thought the following jQuery was correct, however it only returns the first value 'BLACK' in the email regardless of what is selected.

Any advice on how to return the selected checkboxes as a list would be much appreciated! Thank you.

*** UPDATED checkbox ID's to be different from each other ***

**PHP & jQUERY:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function sendSupplierForm() {
            
            var data = {
                ordernumber: $("#ordernumber").val(),
                servicelist: $("#servicelist").val(),
            };

            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "email.php",
            data: data,
            dataType:'text',
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
            $("#EmailStatus").html(data);
            },
            error:function (){}
            });
}
</script>

<div id="SupplierForm">
           <div id="EmailStatus"></div>
           <input type="text" name="ordernumber" id="ordernumber" value="456122"><br>
           <input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist1" value="BLACK">Black<br>
           <input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist2" value="RED">Red<br>
           <input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist3" value="YELLOW">Yellow<br>
           <div name="submit" class="btnAction" onClick="sendSupplierForm();">Send</div>
</div>
```

**email.php**

```
<?php
$mailto = "info@******.com";
$subject = "Test Form";
$headers = "From: info@******.com\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$message = "
<html>
<head>
       <title>Supplier Form Details</title>
</head>
<body>
       <p>Original Order Number: " . $_POST['ordernumber'] . "</p>
       <p>Service List: " . $_POST['servicelist'] . "</p>
</body>
</html>
";

// PHP MAILER FUNCTION
$result1 = mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

// PHP MAILER MESSAGE
if ($result1) {
       print "<p class='success'>SUCCESS!!! The details have been sent.</p>";
       } else {
       print "<p class='Error'>ERROR... Sorry there is a problem sending the details.</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thank you to **@Aro** & **@ArkDevLarry**!

There were two main issues with my code. First, the jQuery was not collecting the values of the checkboxes as mentioned by @Aro, and second, I was too focused on the jQuery and forgot to 'implode' the array of values as mentioned by @ArkDevLarry.

Both suggestions helped me work out the following code which is working perfectly.

I hope this helps someone else who is looking for a similar solution!

**Form PHP & JQUERY:**
(Note: Make sure your path to email.php is correct)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function sendSupplierForm() {
        
        let values = [];
        $("input[name='servicelist[]']:checked").each(function() {
             values.push($(this).val());
        });
        
        var data = {
            ordernumber: $("#ordernumber").val(),
            servicelist: values
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "email.php",
        data: data,
        dataType:'text',
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $("#EmailStatus").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
}
</script>

<div id="SupplierForm">
    <div id="EmailStatus"></div>
    <input type="text" name="ordernumber" id="ordernumber" value="1234567890"><br>
    <input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist1" value="BLACK" >Black<br>
    <input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist2" value="RED" checked >Red<br>
    <input class="list" type="checkbox" name="servicelist[]" id="servicelist3" value="YELLOW" checked >Yellow<br>
    <div name="submit" class="btnAction" onClick="sendSupplierForm();">Send</div>
</div>
```

**email.php**
(Note: Make sure you change the email addresses for it to work)

```
<?php
$mailto = "info@******.com";
$subject = "Test";
$headers = "From: info@******.com\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

$seperate = implode("<br>",$_POST['servicelist']);

$message = "
<html>
<head>
  <title>Supplier Form Details</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Original Order Number: " . $_POST['ordernumber'] . "</p>
  <p>Service List: <br>" . $seperate . "</p>
</body>
</html>
";

$result1 = mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($result1) {
print "<p class='success'>SUCCESS!!! The details have been sent.</p>";
} else {
print "<p class='Error'>ERROR... Sorry there is a problem sending the details.</p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery by default selects the first element so you should take all checkboxes and collect values

```
function sendSupplierForm() {
        
         let values = [];
        $("input[name='servicelist']:checked").each(function() {
             values.push($(this).val());
        });
        var data = {
            ordernumber: $("#ordernumber").val(),
            servicelist: values
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "email.php",
        data: data,
        dataType:'text',
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $("#EmailStatus").html(data);
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
```

}

Also, you have added the same id for all checkboxes, it is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just trying this now and instead of returning the first value, it is now blank, there is no value showing at all. Any ideas?

Comment: I have now managed to get this working by adding [ ] to your sample code: `$("input[name='servicelist[]']:checked").each(function() {` i will continue to do some testing before marking this as solved.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. You can use class instend of name. Also if there any new questions please ask.

Answer (score 1):

The POST values are to be received in the email.php. You cannot treat the servicelist key as a string it is an array of values therefore, you need to loop through Like this.

```
"<body>";
    "<p>Original Order Number: " . $_POST['ordernumber'] . "</p>";
    "<p>Service List: ";
        //these lines can be written above.
        $seperate = implode(",",$_POST['servicelist']);
        $serviceList = trim(",",$seperate);
        //these lines can be written above.
        echo $serviceList;
    "</p>";
"</body>";
```

I hope this solves your problem :).

Comment: Thanks! This has been very helpful. So far I have this working by using $seperate on it's own. The $servicelist line was not working. I will continue to test and mark this as solved later on.

Comment: the `trim` function is not need for this to work, so trash out the $serviceList variable and everything assigned to it. `implode` should work fine.

Comment: David Smith's observation is very correct.

`$("input[name='servicelist']:checked").each(function() {
             values.push($(this).val());
 });`

                                                                                                                                   Add `[]` to the name of the input.

This is because there are more than one input that carries the name servicelist. Adding `[]` to it helps store all values from the inputs into an array.

This array is sent to your `email.php` file where it should be treated as an array.